# Apache "404 not found error"

Tags: python, web-server, apache-httpd

I previously posted a similar question because I used to get a 403 error message (Forbidden). So I decided to get a new micro SD card, and I installed a fresh Apache server then I re-followed this tutorial from scratch again

http://raspberrywebserver.com/cgiscripting/rpi-temperature-logger/

The python files work perfectly, no errors at all. However, I am not able to see the webpage, I get a "404 Not found" error.

I have to mention that the home page (my Raspberry Pi IP address) shows Apache's message "it works". I get the "Not Found" error when I try to access http://localhost/cgi-bin/webgui.py . This makes me think that the problem is related to webgui.py file that I have in the /usr/lib/cgi-bin directory. The owner of this file is www-data.

Below is the content of the error log file:

```
[Sat Feb 06 06:09:57.064276 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 06 06:09:57.065180 2016] [core:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Feb 06 06:34:54.636785 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Feb 06 06:34:54.686137 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 06 06:34:54.686303 2016] [core:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Feb 06 06:40:57.310454 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Feb 06 06:40:57.370112 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 06 06:40:57.370250 2016] [core:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Feb 06 06:48:38.331262 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Feb 06 06:48:38.374504 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 06 06:48:38.374642 2016] [core:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Feb 06 06:54:27.344333 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Feb 06 06:54:27.396548 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 06 06:54:27.396689 2016] [core:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Feb 06 06:56:31.820692 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Feb 06 06:56:31.884533 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 06 06:56:31.884664 2016] [core:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Feb 06 06:58:53.227557 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Feb 06 06:58:53.277910 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 06 06:58:53.278082 2016] [core:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Feb 06 07:04:22.082634 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23244:tid 1996058624] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Feb 06 01:04:22.660809 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6529:tid 1996279808] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 06 01:04:22.661581 2016] [core:notice] [pid 6529:tid 1996279808] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Feb 06 01:15:24.857952 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6529:tid 1996279808] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Feb 06 01:15:24.912566 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6529:tid 1996279808] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 06 01:15:24.912741 2016] [core:notice] [pid 6529:tid 1996279808] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Here is the ls -al in both locations

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/lib/cgi-bin $ ls -al
total 48
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data  4096 Feb  6 00:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 83 root     root     12288 Feb  6 00:09 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  8747 Feb  6 00:28 Adafruit_BME280.py
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  6428 Feb  6 00:32 Adafruit_BME280.pyc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  1272 Feb  6 00:24 BME280.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  7368 Feb  6 00:47 webgui.py
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/lib/cgi-bin $ cd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd /var/www
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www $ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Feb  6 00:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root     root     4096 Feb  6 00:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Feb  6 00:09 html
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    0 Feb  6 00:46 weather.db
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 2048 Feb  6 00:46 weatherlog.db
```

and finally here is the content of the file named serve-cgi-bin.conf

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfDefine ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                        AddHandler cgi-script .py
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </IfDefine>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured it out, what I did is I added this line

```
Require all granted
```

between the directory tages to the etc/apache2/conf-avilable/serve-cgi-bin.conf. Then I added the following line to the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Then

```
a2enmod cgi
service apache2 restart
```